# How can I call Paypal ws with Spring Ws marshall?

Tags: java, web-services, paypal

I'am facing some issues with paypal ws because they have to include custom http headers.

This is the wsdl:

https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts/API_operation?wsdl

I download their API and I have the java classes to Marshall but I do not know how to include the headers.

In soapUi I can include the headers and see the generated in Raw tab like:

```
POST https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptiveAccounts HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "urn:GetVerifiedStatus"
X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: 13XXXXX113
X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
X-PAYPAL-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL: SOAP11
X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME: GetVerifiedStatus
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: A8opbtJy-VMKZ8uQWERT5i54.3GnZA1SCkKHdo4sRg7ep4pSMrq6hZ3Lx
X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-EMAIL-ADDRESS: abcdef_1348660087_biz@hotmail.com
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: abcdef_1348660087_biz_api1.hotmail.com
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: svcs.sandbox.paypal.com
Content-Length: 631
```

I tried to unsuccessible include them into my ws-config.xml as property of bean webServiceTemplate and also try to use a callBackFunction when calling the webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive but it never works

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These SO posts [How to access HTTP headers in Spring-ws endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975694/how-to-access-http-headers-in-spring-ws-endpoint) and [Setting a custom HTTP header dynamically with Spring-WS client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169237/setting-a-custom-http-header-dynamically-with-spring-ws-client) will show you how to add custom HTTP headers.  All you then have to do is add the PayPal specific ones.