# Spring add header to Outgoing requests

Tags: spring, http-headers, spring-3

I want to add a Authorization header to all outgoing requests of my Spring 3.2 application.

This solution describes how to do it by adding an interceptor to a web service template (e.g. RestTemplate):

[Setting a custom HTTP header dynamically with Spring-WS client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169237/setting-a-custom-http-header-dynamically-with-spring-ws-client)

Is there a way to do it without adding interceptors to my restTemplates? Globally, for all outgoing request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set header no cache in spring mvc 3 by annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364622/how-to-set-header-no-cache-in-spring-mvc-3-by-annotation)

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand how I would use WebContentInterceptor to add headers to outgoing requests. Maybe because the examples that I find intercept inbound requests or outbound responses (whereas I want to intercept outbound requests that my applications makes to another application).

My idea at the moment is:

- extend org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor (could I also implement HandlerInterceptor?)
- override prehandle(…) 
- add the header to the HttpServletRequest in prehandle()

Is that correct?

Comment: As far as I understand this is not working for outgoing requests. Any other ideas are appreciated.